# Application not hitting javascript breakpoints on first run

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

For an MVC 4 app, I have breakpoints in both my C# code in visual studio (2013) and my javascript code in chrome developer tools. On the first run of my application, my javascript breakpoints are not hit, and the exception I expect to be thrown is not. However, when I reload hard empty cache, the breakpoints are hit and the error message I expect appears, and will do so no matter how many times I refresh and try again. But when I stop and rerun the application, the first run will not hit the breaks but the reload will. What am I missing? Where can I start fixing this error?

Comment: Which breakpoints do not get triggered, in Chrome or in VS?

Comment: Sounds like the code that's breaking only runs when the page isn't loaded from cache?

Comment: try using IE for testing breakpoints in js

Comment: @Knelis The ones in chrome (javascript)

Comment: ps: breakpoints will not be hit in chome if you want to debug javascript file in VS

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Is there a way to disable loading from cache when running?

Comment: Sure, in the Chrome dev tools under settings you can disable cache when the dev tools are open. It's one of the options.

Comment: put `debugger;` in your javascript, for chrome only

Comment: @MihaiTibrea I have breakpoints for c# in VS and for js in chrome. The ones in chrome hit only after I reload hard, but do not hit on the initial run. I tried the same process in explorer, and the js breakpoints are never hit which is either a step forward or my lack of knowledge using the IE debugger. Will keep testing with IE to see where I get to

Comment: I thought you had breakpoints inside VS on you js code.

Comment: @wayne saw that on another person's thread before making this one. Gave it a shot but it did not work for me. Thank you for the help though!